# Can we partition a phoenix table and overwrite data existing in a single partition?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

Our requirement is to partition phoenix table by a column and overwriting the records at the partition level from SPARK .

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of partitioning in phoenix tables , we have salting which will distribute the data and ordering will be in a random manner .

We can overwrite the data in phoenix tables from spark using 
df.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode("overwrite").option("table", tableToSave).option("query", "select * from '' where'' ").option("zkUrl", zkUrl).save()
Based on the condition we can overwrite the data